# Ionic 2 - Potential typescript circular include cycle that refuses to be broken, causing error

Tags: typescript, angular, ionic2

I've been working with Ionic 2 to build a mobile app and basically I'm stuck in a situation where I'm getting an error like this:

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Unexpected directive value 'undefined' on the View of component 'TopicFeedPage'
```

I have a feed page (feed.html, feed.ts) that contains a component (`<post-added>`) like this:

```
<ion-list [hidden]="chosenFilter !== 'all'">
    <ion-card class="post-card" *ngFor="#post of posts">

      <!-- Post Added -->
      <post-added *ngIf="post.vfeedtype === 1" [post]="post"></post-added>
    </ion-card>
  </ion-list>
```

Inside the component, I have a button that pushes to a page that is a separate type of feed where I'm trying to use the same component (pretty much exact same code). However, in the .ts file for the second feed, when I try to add the directive for the component in the @Page object, it gives me the error above.

Here is the code for the `<post-added>` component:

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {TopicFeedPage} from '../../pages/topic-feed/topic-feed';
import {PostAddedDetailPage} from '../../pages/post-added-detail/post-added-detail';

@Component({
  selector: 'post-added',
  templateUrl: 'build/components/post-added/post-added.html'
})
export class PostAdded {
  @Input() post: any;

  constructor(private nav: NavController) {}

  goToFeedTopic() {
    this.nav.push(TopicFeedPage, this.post);
  }

  goToPost() {
    this.nav.push(PostAddedDetailPage, this.post);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.title = this.post.title.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
  }
}
```

After some research, I found that the error could be due to a circular typescript include cycle and that I should utilize forward references. I have tried all of this and still am getting the same error. Would anyone be able to shed some light on this for me? I'm still new to Angular 2.

Here is the code for the second feed that gets the error from above (topic-feed.html, topic-feed.ts):

```
import {Page, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Component, Inject, forwardRef} from 'angular2/core';
import {TopicData} from '../../providers/topic-data/topic-data';
import {PostAdded} from '../../components/post-added/post-added';


@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/topic-feed/topic-feed.html',
  directives: [PostAdded]
})
export class TopicFeedPage {

  topic: any;
  topicData: any;
  topicDetail: any;
  topicName: any;
  posts: any;
  topicInfo: any;

  constructor(
    private navParams: NavParams,
    private topicFeed: TopicData,
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => PostAdded)) PostAdded
  ) {
    this.topic = navParams.data;

    this.topicDetail = JSON.parse(this.topic.details);

    // Pull the topic name out
    this.topicName = this.topicDetail.topic.topicName;

    // Get the Topic data
    this.topicFeed.getSingleTopicFeed(this.topicDetail.topic.topicId).then(data => {
      this.posts = data.feed;
      this.topicInfo = data.topic;
    });
  }
}
```

Thankya thankya!

Comment: I got the same problem. Were you be able to solve it somehow??

Comment: Yes I was. I ended up just including the directives at the app.ts level instead of trying to include them at the component level. I figure I use them enough that it's okay. It's probably not the best, but it works for now. I hope that helps!

Comment: I was already using this trick in Ionic Beta 6 but when migrating to Beta 8 it looks like i can't include the directive at the app level. Do you have any issue with Beta 8?

Comment: OK it was fixed using ```forwardRef```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: I ended up including the directives at the app.ts (app.js) level instead of at the individual @page or @component level. Basically the same includes and same directives: [PostAdded] but just at a more global level.

There may be a better way, but I found this works for now and I can access the directives anywhere without multiple includes.

Comment: You may also want to look at ```forwardRef``` : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/forwardRef-function.html